# Im trying to detect circle only at real-time webcam, and draw circle on it

Tags: javascript, opencv, shapes

I trying to detect circle only on real-time webcam video and trying to draw circle border on my targeted circle, but right now I can draw a circle on output on a random target, please help me to get the circle target. I'm developing this code in javascript and using opencv.js. That random detection also detecting on video bottom only not in any other places.

```
function processVideo() {
try {
    if (!streaming) {
        // clean and stop.
        src.delete();
        dst.delete();
        dstC1.delete();
        dstC3.delete();

        return;
    }

    let begin = Date.now();
    // start processing.
    cap.read(src);
    cv.cvtColor(src, dst, cv.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
    cv.blur(dst, dstC1, ksize, anchor, cv.BORDER_DEFAULT); // blur the image to avoids noise 
    cv.Canny(dstC1, dstC1, 50, 100, 3, false); // black and white border 

    let contours = new cv.MatVector();
    let hierarchy = new cv.Mat();

    cv.findContours(dstC1, contours, hierarchy, cv.RETR_CCOMP, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, offset = new cv.Point(0, 0));

    let cnt = contours.get(0);

    let contoursColor = new cv.Scalar(255, 255, 255);
    let circleColor = new cv.Scalar(255, 0, 0);
    let circle = cv.minEnclosingCircle(cnt);// this one for circle
    cv.drawContours(dstC1, contours, 0, contoursColor, 1, 8, hierarchy, 100);
    for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        cv.circle(dstC1, circle.center, circle.radius, circleColor, 3);

    }
    cv.imshow('canvasOutput', dstC1);

    let delay = 1000/FPS - (Date.now() - begin);
    setTimeout(processVideo, delay);
} catch (err) {
    utils.printError(err);
}
};
```

Comment: whats the error? here is for debuging and you are not showing any input, current output and intended output. If you need a freelancer to help you write project, here is not the right place

Comment: I'm getting a webcam video output with cv.canny black and white lines of an input object and detecting random lines and bottom area with white circle one random target. Right now it's not detecting any proper target so I need to detect any circle or rectangle target to detect. is there is any code is missing to get what I want? guide me, please. Thank you

Comment: Anyone can find what did I miss from this code to get a proper circle detection in a video?